# WebPart Does Not show up in Gallery

Tags: web-part

As a noob taking a training class, I have created a very simple sandbox solution in VS2010 with the VS2010 SP Power tools. The solution has one webpart with one button. It deploys to my site, the feature activates, but the web part does not show up in the gallery. I do not get any errors when I deploy and the webpart does have a SafeControlEntry. What would cause this, How can i troubleshoot? 
TIA
Dean

Comment: Check to see if you have the public deceleration on your web parts class. #1 reason for it not working. #2 is it isn't registered as a safe control.

Comment: check in custom block in WP gallery... or in category which you have specified

Comment: Are you tried to sort WP gallery  with modified date disc to check what's the latest web parts have been added ,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your Web-part might not be included in the feature you mentioned, have you checked that? If not, you can do it by opening the feature item in the solution manager of VS2010, your Web-part should be listed on the right under the "Items in this feature" list and not "Items in this solution". If not, double click it to send it to the right section.

If that's not the case, you might also want to make sure that you are looking in the right place while trying to add the Web-part. By default your Web-part should be listed under the "Custom" category. So assuming you are adding it from the edit mode of a SharePoint page in your browser you should first select the "Custom" folder from the categories on the left side of your page to view it.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Additionally, you can see if its listed by accessing the web part gallery directly. http://<sharepointurl>/_catalogs/wp. This will provide you a list of all of the web parts.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you couple of work around, first make sure you have a safe control entry for web-part so that it is successfully loaded into the global assembly cache (gac), full trust permission is needed to deploy the web-parts.

Second, check to see if the wsp package you build (you can get those on bin/debug/ and open as xml extension to see if it has included references for your web-part associated with your feature). Can also see it on visual studio project detail file to see if it has your files included there.

Third, see in the custom web-pats section in the web-parts gallery if it exists there (better you go and see at the site level (top level) gallery for web-parts and find if your .dwp exists there, if not be sure its not deployed).

Hope this helps.